# star wars api, how do I get values from api?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using the https://swapi.dev/api/people/ and I'm having an interesting issue with an api I haven't encountered before. Here is an example response of the first value form the api using `https://swapi.dev/api/people/`

```
[
  {
    "name": "Luke Skywalker",
    "height": "172",
    "mass": "77",
    "hair_color": "blond",
    "skin_color": "fair",
    "eye_color": "blue",
    "birth_year": "19BBY",
    "gender": "male",
    "homeworld": "http://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/",
    "films": [
      "http://swapi.dev/api/films/1/",
      "http://swapi.dev/api/films/2/",
      "http://swapi.dev/api/films/3/",
      "http://swapi.dev/api/films/6/"
    ],
    "species": [],
    "vehicles": [
      "http://swapi.dev/api/vehicles/14/",
      "http://swapi.dev/api/vehicles/30/"
    ],
    "starships": [
      "http://swapi.dev/api/starships/12/",
      "http://swapi.dev/api/starships/22/"
    ],
    "created": "2014-12-09T13:50:51.644000Z",
    "edited": "2014-12-20T21:17:56.891000Z",
    "url": "http://swapi.dev/api/people/1/"
  },
]
```

The value I want to get is the first value of the `films` array, which I can achieve however its just a url. I'd need to somehow grab that url, make an api call with it and then get the first film. An example response after calling the api for the first value of films looks like this:

```
{
  "title": "The Empire Strikes Back",
  "episode_id": 5,
  "opening_crawl": "It is a dark time for the\r\nRebellion. Although the Death\r\nStar has been destroyed,\r\nImperial troops have driven the\r\nRebel forces from their hidden\r\nbase and pursued them across\r\nthe galaxy.\r\n\r\nEvading the dreaded Imperial\r\nStarfleet, a group of freedom\r\nfighters led by Luke Skywalker\r\nhas established a new secret\r\nbase on the remote ice world\r\nof Hoth.\r\n\r\nThe evil lord Darth Vader,\r\nobsessed with finding young\r\nSkywalker, has dispatched\r\nthousands of remote probes into\r\nthe far reaches of space....",
  "director": "Irvin Kershner",
  "producer": "Gary Kurtz, Rick McCallum",
  "release_date": "1980-05-17",
}
```

I've never used an api that has urls as values, any ideas on how this might work?

Here is my current code:

Page.jsx

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import '../css/Page.css';
import axios from 'axios';

const Page = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]); 

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(
        "https://swapi.dev/api/people/"
      );
      setData(res?.data.results);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [])

  const mapData = () => {
    if(data && data.length > 0) {
       return (
         <>
          {data.map(item => (
            <div className="itemContainer" key={item.name}>
              <div className="image"><img src="" alt=""/></div>
              <div className="content">
                <span className="title">Name: </span><span className="name">{item.name}</span>
                <br />
                <span className="title">Birthyear: </span><span className="name">{item.birth_year}</span>
                <br />
                <span className="title">Homeworld: </span><span className="name">{item.homeworld}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))} 
        </>
       )
    }
  }

 return (
    <div className="container"> 
       {mapData()}
    </div>
 );
}

export default Page;
```

Comment: When showing data, to make it easier to read, please use `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2))`, or pull the JSON straight from the Network tab of your browser's Developer Tools.

Comment: It sounds like you want to take that first film URL from `results`, and then make a second async network request with that URL as the first argument to an `axiox.get` call? If so, what part of that are you stuck on?

Comment: I'm stuck on the part of how that would actually all work.. so I get you wanna grab that url and make a second call but how then will I map that into my results? I'm struggling to get how this function would look.

Comment: You can pass just any URL to axios call, and it would work.

Comment: There should be a button (like Show Details) to load further (child - `http://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/`) APIs after loading data for parent (from `https://swapi.dev/api/people/`).

Comment: What are you trying to build? Do you have some image or wireframe?